# Lumen phpunit get request fails and gives 500 when I access the uri parameter via $request->route('whatever')

Tags: unit-testing, testing, laravel-5, lumen

I'm sending a `GET` request via Lumen unit testing using

`$this->get('api/cars/volvo/')`

where *volvo* is a route parameter.

When this request reaches my controller, it returns a `500` response because I'm accessing the URI parameter through

`$request->route('company')`

Note that this only occurs when I send request through unit test, not the normal request if I send for example from Postman.

Example:

```php
$response = $this->get('/api/v1/cars/volvo', $header);
$response->assertResponseStatus(200);
```

I get the following when I run this test:

```
1) Tests\ApiTest::test_get_cars
Expected status code 200, got 500.
Failed asserting that 500 matches expected 200.
```

Comment: What do you mean by because `I'm accessing the URI parameter through $request->route('company')`? Where are you doing that in the code you have displayed?

Comment: Plus, can you post the exact error other than the status code 500, from laravel.log file?

Comment: @Learner in controller file I'm accessing the volvo as a uri parameter like $request->route('company'). And I'm getting it. But when I test the same endpoint through unit test, then the above mentioned error occurs. 
And I'm not sure where can I get the laravel.log file. Note that I'm using lumen, because I'm building and api

Comment: Even if you are using Lumen..the log file should still be at: storage/logs folder...pleasd have a look in there ad paste the exact error you are getting